How to create Langfuse Trace via .Net code
I am developing an AI solution which combine of .Net and Python app. The reason for Python app is mostly to communicate with OpenAI and Langfuse. I want to cut off the Python app to make solution simpler and easier to deploy, but couldn't find a way to write Langfuse trace via its API. Does anyone know what is the endpoint and payload to do it?

You need to use the ingestion endpoint: https://api.reference.langfuse.com/#post-/api/public/ingestion
You can also download the OpenAPI spec for types at the very top of the reference.
